# pragma in `#define` macro to disable warnings

Tags: c++, c, macros

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define DISABLE_WARNINGS() \
        #pragma warning( push, 0 )
#elif __GNUC__
#define DISABLE_WARNINGS() \
        #define DISABLE_WARNINGS \
        #pragma GCC diagnostic push \
        #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#endif
```

I would like to define a single macro such as "DISABLE_WARNINGS" in my code before including 3rd party headers that produce enormous amount of warnings on **W4**, and also ensure the code compiles on any platform.

For example:

```
DISABLE_WARNINGS
#include <gtkmm/buttonbox.h>
#include <gtkmm/box.h>
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
ENABLE_WARNINGS
```

What would be the best way to achieve this with single macro?

Comment: I am not sure, but I doubt if you can have one `#define` macro containing more `#..` statements, especially separated by `\<newline>` Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532309/multiple-preprocessor-directives-on-one-line-in-c Your macro is logically doing same thing.

Comment: See my edit and then please give me a link to duplicate for g++

Comment: @hvd, the duplicate doesn't answer how to deal with a conditional compilation between platforms (MS - GNU C), voting to reopen.

Comment: @AlterMann Er... what? That's just a matter of putting the right `#define` between the right `#if`/`#endif`, something the OP already understands and put in the question already.

Comment: @codekiddy The other question *does* answer that already: use `_Pragma`. You already have the `#pragma` directives to use with GCC.

Comment: @hvd, in this way both ENABLE_WARNING and DISABLE_WARNING are defined, I think OP wants to enable/disable warnings under some condition, isn't it?

Comment: @hvd I still can't see how to embed two _Pragma operators into one macro? GCC requires 2 times #pragma to disable warnings.. I may be wrong since I don't have g++ compiler right now to test it.

Comment: @codekiddy You can just use two `_Pragma`s in a row.

Comment: @hvd OK, thank's for that. I'll do so then.

Comment: @codekiddy BTW, I don't know if you're aware of this, but `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"` only covers warnings that are enabled *directly* by `-Wall`, it doesn't cover warnings that are enabled by some other option that also gets enabled by `-Wall`. Depending on what you get, you may need to suppress other warnings as well (which is a simple matter of adding yet another `_Pragma`).

Comment: @hvd thanks, **warning( push, 0 )** is not able so disable all warning on MSVC on **Wall** either, in both cases it works to compile with W4

Comment: For reference, I had closed this as a duplicate of [pragma in define macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/pragma-in-define-macro), and the question should have remained closed as a duplicate. (Which does not mean your question is a bad one.) I welcome anyone to re-close it.

Comment: @codekiddy You're not using the right syntax for `_Pragma`. As explained in the answer to that other question, `_Pragma` takes a string literal (unlike MSVC's `__pragma`).

Comment: @codekiddy `"GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall""` is not a valid string literal. String literals cannot contain unescaped double quotes.

Comment: Please consider turning your EDIT2 into an answer. If you do I want to upvote it !

Comment: [You're not supposed to use `/W4` anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/thxezb7y(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Just lower your warning level to something more sensible. `/W2` or _maybe_ `/W3` is usually appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In C99 mode, you can use `_Pragma` instead of `#pragma`:

```
#define DISABLE_WARNINGS \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wall\"")
```